# undefined variable: Customers Laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy intentando hacer un dropdown list con un foreach en laravel pero me da el error undefined variable: Customers.

Les muestro como lo estoy haciendo en mi vista add-customers.blade.php:

```
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="account">Tipo de cuenta</label>
                            <select name="account" id="" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Seleccione el tipo de cuenta</option>
                                @foreach ($customers as $customer)
                                <option value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->account}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

Este es el codigo de mi controlador con las funciones:

CustomersController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\Product;
use App\Model\Supplier;
use App\Model\Unit;
use App\Model\Category;
use App\Model\Purchase;
use App\Model\Invoice;
use App\Model\InvoiceDetail;
use App\Model\Payment;
use App\Model\PaymentDetail;
use App\Model\Customer;
use Auth;
use Session;
use DB;
use PDF;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function view(){ 
        $allData = Customer::all();
        return view('backend.customer.view-customer', compact('allData'));
    }

    public function add(){
        return view('backend.customer.add-customer');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->holding = $request->holding;
        /*$customer->name = $request->name;*/
        $customer->company = $request->company;
        $customer->legal_entity = $request->legal_entity;
        /*$customer->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;
        $customer->mobile_two = $request->mobile_two;
        $customer->mobile_three = $request->mobile_three;*/
        $customer->email = $request->email;
       /* $customer->position = $request->position;*/
        $customer->country = $request->country;
        $customer->state = $request->state;
        $customer->city = $request->city;
        $customer->address = $request->address;
        $customer->postal = $request->postal;
        $customer->cuit = $request->cuit;
        $customer->website = $request->website;
        $customer->id_parentCompany = $request->id_parentCompany;
        $customer->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
        $customer->save();
        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('customers.view');
    }

    public function edit($id){
        $editData = Customer::find($id);
        return view('backend.customer.edit-customer', compact('editData'));
    }

    public function detail($id){
        $detailData = Customer::find($id);
        return view('backend.customer.detail', compact('detailData'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id){
        $customer = Customer::find($id);
        $customer->name = $request->name;
        $customer->company = $request->company;
        $customer->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;
        $customer->mobile_two = $request->mobile_two;
        $customer->mobile_three = $request->mobile_three;
        $customer->email = $request->email;
        $customer->position = $request->position;
        $customer->country = $request->country;
        $customer->state = $request->state;
        $customer->city = $request->city;
        $customer->address = $request->address;
        $customer->postal = $request->postal;
        $customer->cuit = $request->cuit;
        $customer->website = $request->website;
        $customer->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        $customer->save();
        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('customers.view');
    }

    public function delete($id){
        $customer = Customer::find($id);
        $customer->delete();
        return redirect()->route('customers.view');
    }
```

No entiendo porque me dice que la variable no esta definida, estoy continuando el proyecto de el programador anterior a mi de la empresa, asi que estoy siguiendo sus metodos y en el caso de las categorias o productos el dropdown funciona pero en la parte de clientes por algun motivo no.

En el caso de las categorias que si funciona asi es el controlador:

CategoriesController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\Category;
use Auth;
use Session;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function view(){ 
        $allData = Category::all();
        return view('backend.category.view-category', compact('allData'));
    }

    public function add(){
        return view('backend.category.add-category');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $category = new Category();
        $category->type = $request->type;
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
        $category->save();
        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('categories.view');
    }

    public function edit($id){
        $editData = Category::find($id);
        return view('backend.category.edit-category', compact('editData'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id){
        $category = Category::find($id);
        $category->type = $request->type;
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        $category->save();
        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('categories.view');
    }

    public function delete($id){
        $category = Category::find($id);
        $category->delete();
        return redirect()->route('categories.view');
    }
}
```

Esta es su respectiva vista:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            <label for="category_id">Categoria</label>
                            <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
                              <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                              @foreach ($categories as $category)
                              <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->type }} - {{ $category->name }}</option>
                              @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

Comment: De acuerdo con el código mostrado el error es perfectamente lógico, en ninguna parte muestras como llega dicha variable a la vista

Comment: @BetaM hay alguna manera de pasarle la variable que no sea compact? Porque no me quiero correr mucho de la manera que programo esto el anterior a mi, a ver si puedo identificar como hizo el para pasar las variables.

Comment: por medio del método compact o de with como segundo argumento en un array asociativo o como un valor disponible para todas las vistas por medio de view share (*que dudo sea el caso*), la cuestión es que intentas iterar una colección que no has hecho llegar a la vista donde planeas mostrar la data

Comment: @BetaM procedí a editar la pregunta y agregue el controlador de categorias y el bloque de código donde utiliza el foreach, ya que no veo la diferencia de donde él pasa la variable y donde yo no lo estoy haciendo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede agrega a tu metodo add la variable $customers.

```
public function add(){ 
   $customers = Category::all();
   return view('backend.category.add-category', compact('customers'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

la variable $customers no la estas enviando a la vista en todo caso seria lo siguiente en tu controlador...para que no modifiques el foreach en la vista.

```
public function view(){ 
    $customers = Category::all();
    return view('backend.category.view-category', compact('customers'));
}
```

Comment: lo hice pero me dice compact():undefined variable customers